# weird output when trying to sum elements in array (using method)

Tags: arrays, sum

I am making a method that adds all the elements in the array. I am getting the array from the testArray1 in main. The output is "[I@15d6c7"

```
public class arrayExercises{
public int ArraySum(int[] array){

int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  sum += array[i];
}
return sum;
}


public static void main(String[] args){

int[] testArray1 = {1,2,3,4};

System.out.println(testArray1);
}
}
```

Comment: NVM i fixed it...I needed to add ArraySum(testArray1) in the output, then "static in the method"  

i guess my question now is, is this the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing out the string representation of testArray1 instead of the sum of its elements.  I think that you want to change your main method as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
      int[] testArray1 = {1,2,3,4};
      System.out.println(ArraySum(testArray1));
 }
```

Comment: yeap, I got it as soon as I posted it on here. Either way, thank you for the answer! is it always going to print out those weird output every time a non-string output is being printed as a string?

Comment: This boils down to the developer of the ToString() method on any particular object.  Some of them impress me with their thoughtfulness and creativity, and others--not so much.